# How does one use prettify function with ioden framework?

Tags: javascript, slider

i want to add a log sliding function as implemented here:

http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/7dbowqfd/

Here is where my function is called:

```
    prettify: function(num) {
        <?
            if(isset($prettify)) echo $prettify;    
        ?>
        return num;
```

Here is where i added prettify code, but breaks everything:

```
    $this->load->view('filter/range', array(
        "title" => "Picks",
        "min"   => "0",
        "max"   => 10000,
        "prettify"  => function (n) {
    var lg = Math.log(n);
    var rLg = +lg.toFixed(2);
    return rLg;
}));
```

I've tried a few other workarounds but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the "ioden" framework?

Comment: I think he means ionden